# Setting featured image from front end form

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, file-upload

So I have been trawling the internet for a few days looking for a solution to this problem. I am trying to set the featured image of a post from the upload input of this form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="quick-post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="input-box" placeholder="What's on your mind?" maxlength="10000" name="quick-post-area" class="col-xs-12"></textarea>
    <!-- images -->
    <fieldset class="images">
    <label for="images">Upload an image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image-uploader" id="img-upload" size="50">
    </fieldset>
    <!-- images end -->
    <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="quick-post-submit">
</form>
```

I am using wp insert post to create a post from this form but the image is not uploaded as it should be. This is the PHP I'm using:

```
<?php 
function quick_post() {

    // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
    $post_id = -1;

    $author_id = 1;
    $slug = 'post';
    global $current_user;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it
    if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'open',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $user_id,
                'post_name'         =>  $slug,
                'post_title'        =>  'Post By: ' . $current_user->user_login,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'         =>  'post',
                'post_content'      =>  $_POST['quick-post-area'],
                'post_category' => array( 3 ),
            )
        );

require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attachmentId = media_handle_upload('image-uploader', $post_ID);
set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, $attachmentId);


    // Otherwise, we'll stop
    } else {

            // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
            $post_id = -2;

    } // end if

} // end programmatically_create_post

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   quick_post();
   header('Location: https://outrankd.com');
}
?>
```

I should also mention that once this is working, I plan to use the Wordpress check filetype function to validate the upload but think that this should work with something like this:

```
if ($attachmentId = wp_check_filetype('image')) {
set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, $attachmentId);
}
```

If anyone could shed some light on where I'm going wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

Comment: Thanks norman. I now have a function that runs perfectly well but am trying to check file type using this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype is it possible to echo the mime type before submitting the form?

Comment: you can check the file type before submitting the form only when you use get method or reading a file from another source. if you are depend on the user to upload image then your code validate the file type, you need wrap your functionality in between post method.

Comment: did you mean wrap it in get methods? This is what I'm using and ideally would like it to check filetype before they hit submit: http://pastebin.com/xtRk4F0Z

Comment: dude you need to use jquery validation engine for form validation it will cover image file type validation on client side, also you can remotely validate user selected image.https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: I was going to do this originally but was led to believe that it could be manipulated for unethical use. That's why I was looking at a more server side PHP solution or does the WP media handle upload already have server side protection against unwanted file types?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106133/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-noman).